# What is the Event id for File & folder creation in Window Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, eventviewer

I have enabled Object level access in event viewer, but i am unable to find the exact date & time, when the user create a file or folder.

Do you know, how to find out the time & date in event viewer??

Below are the print-screen attached.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This can be rather challenging task to analyze all of these events.

I would read more about a variety of event IDs related to Object access [here](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/wiki/WindowsSecuritySettings/65).
Article also provides examples of events, which can definitely be useful.

[Example 1](http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4656)

[Example 2](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4663)

I would probably search for some third-party auditing software with a more flexible settings or you will also need some sort of log-analyzer.